# Android Listview based on SimpleAdapter Includes Image Descriptions When Searching Using Textwatcher

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have an android ListView hooked up to a Simpleadapter.  It outputs specific static images as icons on the listview depending on text content of some elements as well as some text titles and sub-titles for those element.

I also have setup a textwatcher for an edittextview to filter and do autosearching.

The searching within the listview runs okay.  However, I have noticed that the textwatcher includes the text content element(now converted into images) in the listview.  So it appears that it is outputting some incorrect rows in the listview as the user only sees the titles/sub-titles and not the text content behind the image icons.

Is there a better way of filtering the listview which would exclude the original text behind the image icons?

Comment: The filter for `SimpleAdapter` checks all the columns from the `Map` of each row by default so you would need to provide your own filter that only uses for filtering the columns you want.

Comment: Thanks @Luksprog.  I ended up doing just that. Basically hooked up a manual filter on the afterTextChanged method of the textwatcher.  Said filter loops thru the whole listview elements and selects those that matches.  The notifydatasetchanged then resets the listview.  Just got me to thinking again if this is the best approach or I should have used a different Adapter.

Comment: That(probably if you tested) works but it's not the best way. The best way would be to make your own `SimpleAdapter` and override the `getFilter()` method to return a custom `Filter` that filters the list like you want. The main reason for this would be the presence of a background thread to do the filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I end up doing (thanks @Luksprog):

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if(s.length()>0){
        int count = viewListAdapter.getCount();
        if(count > 0){
            hashMapListForListViewcopy.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Map temp = (Map) viewListAdapter.getItem(i);
                String txtOfferName = temp.get("txtOfferName").toString();
                HashMap<String, String> entitiesHashMap;
                entitiesHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                if (txtOfferName.toLowerCase().contains(s.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    System.out.println("Found a match!");
                    Log.v("txtOfferName", txtOfferName);
                    Log.v("viewListAdapter.getItem(i)","" + viewListAdapter.getItem(i));
                    entitiesHashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) viewListAdapter.getItem(i);
                    hashMapListForListViewcopy.add(entitiesHashMap);
                }
            }
        }   
        viewListAdaptercopy.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```