# Filter for listview with multiple textview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ListView with 3 TextViews. And I want to build a filter to filter just the first TextView.
But the filter I built is now filtering all items in the ListView.
Is there any way to filter only a specific TextView?

```
        ...
    filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.building_list.search_box);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] {KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_DATE, KEY_LINK }, new int[] {
             R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.date, R.id.link});
    Filter filterx = ((Filterable) adapter).getFilter();
    setListAdapter(adapter);
        ...
```

Comment: The default `Filter` of the default `SimpleAdapter` will use all of the columns for the row's `Map` for filtering. You would need to implement your own filter which will consider for filtering only the data for the first `TextView`. Or a manual approach from a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448691/android-listview-based-on-simpleadapter-includes-image-descriptions-when-searchi#comment18416730_13448691 .

Answer (score 0):

Place the contents of three `TextView`'s in a class called `Data` :

```
public class Data {
    public final String text1;
    public final String text2;
    public final String text3;

    public Data(String t1, String t2, String t3){
      this.text1 = t1;
      this.text2 = t2;
      this.text3 = t3;
    }

    @Override
    public final String toString(){
      return text1;
    }
}
```

Now use a collection of `Data` objects in your adapter. The default `Filterable` implementation of adapter uses `toString()` of its objects to filter, which in this case is `text1`. Hence, adapter will filter based on `text1`.